# Using the "httpd" Chef cookbook, httpd is killed after every request

Tags: apache, centos, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm provisioning a vagrant vm using `chef_solo`, using `bento/centos7.2`. I'm installing `httpd` through the [httpd cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/httpd) with the following code.

```
# Install Apache and starts it
httpd_service 'mine' do
    mpm 'prefork'
    action [:create, :start]
    listen_ports ['80', '443']
    run_user node['webserver']['run_user'] # the value is 'vagrant'
end

# Add the site configuration
httpd_config 'mine' do
    instance 'mine'
    source 'mine.conf.erb'
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Create document rood directory
directory "#{node['webserver']['document_root']}" do
    recursive true
end

# Homepage
template "#{node['webserver']['document_root']}/index.php" do
    source 'index.php.erb'
    mode '0644'
    owner node['webserver']['user']
    group node['webserver']['group']
    action :create_if_missing
end

# Install the mod_php Apache module.
httpd_module 'php' do
    instance 'mine'
end

# Install memcached
package 'memcached'

# Install php-pecl-memcache
package 'php-pecl-memcache' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Install php-pecl-memcached
package 'php-pecl-memcached' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Install php-mysql
package 'php-mysql' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Install php-pdo
package 'php-pdo' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Install php-intl
package 'php-intl' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end

# Install php-mssql
package 'php-mssql' do
  action :install
  notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[mine]'
end
```

Funny thing is, When I run `kitchen converge` everything is good and `httpd` works perfectly (InSpec test pass, and I manually verify with `kitchen login`).

But when I run on vagrant, it is killed from the very beginning, and it dies after each request. I don't know why, nor I know if there is any log I can read to debug this behavior. Any ideas?

**UDPATE:**

[This is the log](http://pastebin.com/A7GyPnNJ) found in `/var/log/httpd-mine/error_log`

[This is the log](http://pastebin.com/2JsVVxjn) in `sudo journalctl`

Comment: What's in the Apache error log or the systemd journal?

Comment: Apache log doesn't have anything (since Apache is dead, it wont log anything). I'm not sure where is the system journal, what's its default location?

Comment: It's not a file, you have to interact with it via `journalctl`. Apache's error log will usually contain something during a crash. Also make sure you aren't hitting the oomkiller (it would have entries in systlog if it was activating).

Comment: @coderanger I updated my answer to include logs.